# Reading dynamic variable from env

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

Say I have an env variable:

```
  echo lmx_setting_foo="bar";
```

the above env variable was created like:

```
$ lmx set foo bar
```

and that did:

```
export "lmx_setting_$2"="$3"
```

Say someone wants to retrieve "foo", they would do:

```
$ lmx get foo
```

but if I do this:

```
echo "$lmx_setting_$2"
```

it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 4):

There's a few ways to go about this, but the most portable is probably

```
eval "echo \$lmx_setting_$2"
```

but the bash-specific way to avoid an eval would be

```
temp="lmx_setting_$2"
echo ${!temp}
```

If you haven't before, you should open the bash man page and scroll down to *Parameter Expansion* to see all your options.  You specifically asked about environment variables, but if you don't need to export these variables and you have a new enough version of bash (4.0+) you can use Associative Arrays and avoid this whole mess  ...but then your script really isn't portable.